# Static site post form to different domain

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic

I am wondering if this is a programmatically possible. I want to have a static site which can also be used to add items on a database existing on a different server and domain.

The flow for posting items is as follows:

> Post Item Details -> Pay -> Confirmation Page

From what I can see, it is possible to post to a different domain (dynamic) like this without needing javascript:

```
<form action="http://post.test.com" id="form" method="post" name="contact-form">
```

My questions about this method are:

1. Can transfer them to the payment page after they have posted the item detail form?
2. What happens if they don't fill out the form correctly, can I send them back to the form if they used invalid values?
3. Is this a good approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try using `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` to transfer them to the payment page.
2. Try using form validation to check if they have filled the form correctly before sending it.

Comment: The issue with this is I can only use javascript form validation. If javascript is disabled, is there a way to transfer them to one page if the submitted the form successfully, or another if there was an error?